# prevent filter with 1 million members from loading

Tags: filter, iccube-reporting

We have a filter `product_id` with about one million members:

```
source = dimension/hierarchy/level product_id
```

That filter is connected to a line chart, where we want to display product prices per day, one line per selected `product_id`. We don't want to see *all* `product_ids` as a list in the filter; we only want the flexibility to choose `product_ids` (more than only one), which should be displayed in the line chart
as separate lines.

Providing that filter as a `multi_select` filter doesn't work since it is not possible to load all these one million members. Is it possible to prevent the filter from loading all of these members?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible in the reporting version 7.x. You might implement this feature using a JS template.

Note that this filter feature will be available in the upcoming reporting v8.

Better to  contact the icCube support for more details.

Comment: okay thanks a lot for your quick feedback.then we need to update to v8 first.